# Can't solve a system of coupled, non-linear differential equations with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

When I give Mathematica this system to solve:

```
system={x'[t] == -x[t]*Sqrt[(x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2], y'[t] == -1 - y[t]*Sqrt[(x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2]}
DSolve[system, {x[t],y[t]},{t}]
```

It just returns

```
 DSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t]*Sqrt[(x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2], y'[t] == -1 - y[t]*Sqrt[(x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2]}, {x[t],y[t]},{t}]
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem than using DSolve?

Also, the physics behind the problem is projectile motion considering quadratic drag force and x(or y) is the projectile's velocity along x(or y) axes. So in the end I would like to have this system solved:

```
system={x''[t] == -x'[t]*Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2], y''[t] == -1 - y'[t]*Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2]}
```

(Where x and y are now projectile displacements, not velocities)

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: FYI: *Mathematica* is case sensitive; your `System` in the second line should match `system` in the first line.  This does not solve your problem but it is the first thing you should correct.

Comment: I just made that mistake in the question, not in Mathematica. Thank you anyways @Mr.Wizard

Answer (score 2):

You can try `NDSolve`

```
sol1[t_] = 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t]*Sqrt[(x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2], 
   y'[t] == -1 - y[t]*Sqrt[(x[t])^2 + (y[t])^2], x[0] == 0.003, 
   y[0] == 0.001}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 500}]
Plot[x[t] /. sol1[t_], {t, 400, 500}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time--->", "x(t)--->"}]
```